# C - How to store 2nd column of file in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, char, token, delimiter

I have a file which stores data in a comma delimited file (Countries.txt) in the following format (this is just a small sample) :

```
AD,Andorra,AN,AD,AND,20.00,Andorra la Vella,Europe,Euro,EUR,67627.00
AE,United Arab Emirates,AE,AE,ARE,784.00,Abu Dhabi,Middle East,UAE Dirham,AED,2407460.00
AF,Afghanistan,AF,AF,AFG,4.00,Kabul,Asia,Afghani,AFA,26813057.00
AG,Antigua and Barbuda,AC,AG,ATG,28.00,Saint John's,Central America and the Caribbean,East Caribbean Dollar,XCD,66970.00
AI,Anguilla,AV,AI,AIA,660.00,The Valley,Central America and the Caribbean,East Caribbean Dollar,XCD,12132.00
```

I want to store the second field of each line such that my array contains only the country names like so:

```
char *countriesArray[4096];
countriesArray[0] = "Andorra"
countriesArray[1] = "United Arab Emirates"
countriesArray[2] = "Afghanistan"
countriesArray[3] = "Antigua and Barbuda"
countriesArray[4] = "Anguilla"
```

But each time I run my code, my array doesn't get populated correctly. I'm quite sure the issue doesn't lie with the tokenizing algorithm, as I can display each token properly once I remove the `if` statement. Here is my code :

```
FILE * fp;
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

int count=0;
ssize_t read;
char *countriesArray[4096];

fp = fopen("Countries.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) 
   {
       printf("First while loop iterating");


       printf("%s", line);





       int index=0;
       char * pch;
       pch = strtok (line,",");
       int i;

       for (i=0; i<2; i++)
       {
           printf("Second while loop iterating");
           printf ("\npch is :%s\n",pch);


           if (index == 1)
           {    
               printf ("\nGoing to assign this to countriesArray:%s\n",pch);
               printf ("\nVariable count is:%d\n",count);
               countriesArray[count]=pch;
           }


           pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
           index++;




       }

       count++;


    }

    printf("countriesArray at index 0 is :%s\n", countriesArray[0]);
    printf("countriesArray at index 1 is :%s\n", countriesArray[1]);
    printf("countriesArray at index 2 is :%s\n", countriesArray[2]);
    printf("countriesArray at index 3 is :%s\n", countriesArray[3]);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        free (countriesArray[i]);
    }

       if (line)
           free(line);
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

**Output** :

```
First while loop iteratingAD,Andorra,AN,AD,AND,20.00,Andorra la Vella,Europe,Euro,EUR,67627.00
Second while loop iterating
pch is :AD
Second while loop iterating
pch is :Andorra

Going to assign this to countriesArray:Andorra

Variable count is:0
First while loop iteratingAE,United Arab Emirates,AE,AE,ARE,784.00,Abu Dhabi,Middle East,UAE Dirham,AED,2407460.00
Second while loop iterating
pch is :AE
Second while loop iterating
pch is :United Arab Emirates

Going to assign this to countriesArray:United Arab Emirates

Variable count is:1
First while loop iteratingAF,Afghanistan,AF,AF,AFG,4.00,Kabul,Asia,Afghani,AFA,26813057.00
Second while loop iterating
pch is :AF
Second while loop iterating
pch is :Afghanistan

Going to assign this to countriesArray:Afghanistan

Variable count is:2
First while loop iteratingAG,Antigua and Barbuda,AC,AG,ATG,28.00,Saint John's,Central America and the Caribbean,East Caribbean Dollar,XCD,66970.00
Second while loop iterating
pch is :AG
Second while loop iterating
pch is :Antigua and Barbuda

Going to assign this to countriesArray:Antigua and Barbuda

Variable count is:3
First while loop iteratingAI,Anguilla,AV,AI,AIA,660.00,The Valley,Central America and the Caribbean,East Caribbean Dollar,XCD,12132.00
Second while loop iterating
pch is :AI
Second while loop iterating
pch is :Anguilla

Going to assign this to countriesArray:Anguilla

Variable count is:4
countriesArray at index 0 is :Anguilla
countriesArray at index 1 is :Anguilla
countriesArray at index 2 is :Anguilla
countriesArray at index 3 is :Anguilla
*** Error in `./chef': free(): invalid pointer: 0x09c1c173 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm really new to C Programming so please give me a chance to learn!

**EDIT** : I've made some progress(see edited code above), now my variables `pch` and `count` are showing correct values inside the `if` statement. But `countriesArray` is still not populating properly

Comment: You are declaring an array of char* pointer, but you still need to allocate storage for each string.

Comment: `countriesArray[count]=pch;` --> `countriesArray[count]=strdup(pch);`

Answer (score 2):

You use repetedly `getline` which allocates a buffer for `line`, and only free one line at the end. For any serious program, it leads to what is called memory leak : you allocate a piece of memory and loose the pointer that could allow to free it. You should have a `char *lines[4096]` array to keep all those lines to be able to correctly free them at the end.

```
char *lines[4096];
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) 
{
    lines[count] = line;
```

and at end of program :

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    free(lines[i];
}
```

(only that ; do not try to free countriesArray elements  as thay are just pointers inside allocated elements, the allocated elements are in `lines`)

But at least, all your `countriesArray` elements point to different memory places.

The real problem in this code is that you set `index` to 0 outside of first loop, like `count`. That's correct for `count` but index must be reset to 0 on each iteration of first loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i've tried what you've suggested and now it goes into an infinite loop.... It just keeps iterating through the second while loop

Comment: I edited my post to stop iterations after second column.

Comment: I could run your program ... after I replaced `free(countriesArray[i])` by `free(lines[i])` and removed `if ...{ free(line); }`. And ... my second loop suggestion was stupid `strok(lines, ",")` is not same as `strok(NULL, ",")` ...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work, thanks to the recommendation provided by @BLUEPIXY. Turns out all I was missing was `strdup`

**Code :**

```
FILE * fp;
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

int count=0;
ssize_t read;


fp = fopen("Countries.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

       while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) 
       {

           int index=0;
           char * pch;
           pch = strtok (line,",");
           int i;

           for (i=0; i<2; i++)
           {



              if (index == 1)
              { 
                    countriesArray[count]=strdup(pch);
              }


              pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
              index++;




           }

       count++;


       }





 if (line)
    free(line);
```